# Can't run git diff --dirstat=files,10,cumulative HEAD^..HEAD

Tags: git, diff

I want to know change status of directory with percentage. So I run like following

## case 1

```
$ git diff --dirstat=files,10,cumulative HEAD^..HEAD
usage: git diff [<options>] [<commit> [<commit>]] [--] [<path>...]
```

## case 2

```
$ git diff --dirstat=11 HEAD^..HEAD
  76.8% api/
  13.0% data/fonts/
```

I have tested this under git 1.7.5.4 and 1.7.0.4. But I don't know why case 1 is not correct command. I checked git diff man page http://goo.gl/GPU49 also git config for diff.dirstat but I can't do it correctly.

Do you have any opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it in my mac and linux server with git version 1.7.6 then there had no problem. But when I tried it in my mac and linux server with git version 1.7.5.4, there had same problem.

```
# git version 1.7.5.4
$ git diff --dirstat=10,lines,cumulative  HEAD^^^^^^^..HEAD
usage: git diff [<options>] [<commit> [<commit>]] [--] [<path>...]

# git version 1.7.6
$ git diff --dirstat=10,lines,cumulative  HEAD^^^^^^^..HEAD
  17.7% core/
  41.9% tools/releasetools/
```

I can't find this fix in git 1.7.6 release note. http://goo.gl/HcPh9 Anyway it's OK in git 1.7.6.

Answer (score 1):

please try

git diff --dirstat=10 **--cumulative** HEAD^..HEAD

sample output on my computer

mvaidya@research:~/git-hub/git.git$ git diff --dirstat=0 --cumulative HEAD^^^^^^^^^^^^..HEAD

12.4% Documentation/RelNotes/

37.1% Documentation/

20.8% builtin/

1.8% gitweb/

14.6% t/

Comment: can you let me know your git version? I tried it in my mac with git 1.7.6 also my original command is operated correctly. Thank you! :)